# how java scala interoperability works?

Tags: java, scala

There are many resources available online to understand this, but still am confused.

I'm using `Apache spark java` api for my work and I can see that some classes are from `scala` too in spark java jars. I believe both languages bytecode (`classes/code compiled from their respective compilers`) sense is similar to JVM if both java and scala code doing the same thing. `( I guess am right here)`

So lets say, I've some code written in scala doing "chow chow chow" work and after compilation its compiled file named as `chow .class`

I've some code written in java too doing "phow phow phow" work and after compilation its compiled file named as `phow.class`

doubts:

1. If I want to use chow.class in java project in eclipse, then If I add this chow.class in my java project, eclipse's decompile would be able to decompile this class so that I could call scala class and see what's there in code and use it too where I want ?
2. How scala's class are bundled in spark java jars ? How its being done ?

my sense are literally stuck to understand this, can anyone share the example steps to understand this process like the way its happening in spark java api ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you encounter specific error?

Comment: @cchantep, its not about error but how its happening ?

Comment: Everything is compile as bytecode, so it just works on JVM. Just try it.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Kotlin and Clojure can also be used with Spark, or any other JVM framework

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Apache spark java api for my work and I can see that some classes are from scala too in spark java jars.

Sure, because most of **Spark** is written in **Scala**.

> I believe both languages bytecode (classes/code compiled from their respective compilers) sense is similar to JVM if both java and scala code doing the same thing. ( I guess am right here)

I don't understand what you are trying to say here.
Both languages compile to the **JVM** bytecode which then is interpreted by a **JVM** when you run it.

> If I want to use chow.class in java project

You just add it to the `CLASSPATH` in any way you prefer, as well as all the dependencies of that class. Just like when you add any **Java** dependency to your **Java** project.

> in eclipse

Your IDE is completely irrelevant for this conversation.

> then If I add this chow.class in my java project, eclipse's decompile would be able to decompile this class so that I could call scala class and see what's there in code and use it too where I want ?

Not sure why you need to decompile it to use it? You don't do that for **Java** code neither.
Anyways, I believe **IntelliJ** had some decompiler and conversion tools, not sure if **Eclipse** has something similar; but again this is not related to anything.

> How scala's class are bundled in spark java jars ? How its being done ?

The same way the **Java** classes are bundled, the build tool they use *(**Maven** IIRC)* was configured to compile both the **Java** and **Scala** source files into `.class` files and then they packaged all those classes into a single `.jar` *(remember a `.jar` is basically a `.zip`)*